# jQuery confirm vs vanilla JS confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.confirmation');
elems.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?');
  });
});

$('.confirmation').on('click', function() {
  return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

What it does is it grabs certain elements and stops the `delete` function which runs in the back end. Now. It works in `jQuery` version. It does not work in `Vanilla` version. In `Vanilla`, even if I click cancel in the confirm box, it still removes the field. `JQuery` on the other hand stops the code.

Is there something I did wrong in vanilla JS or does jQuery have some 'magic' in the background?

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the removing process?

Comment: Note that not all browsers support `forEach()` on the collection returned from `querySelectorAll()`. Try `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('...'), function(element) { /* your logic here... */ });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about confirm, it works the same way; it's about syntax sugar provided by jQuery. And this is the key difference:

> Returning false from an event handler (set with jQuery) will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

On the contrary, event listener set with native API doesn't have this feature. To use it, you have to modify the code a bit:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?');
  if (!confirmation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

It's `stopPropagation()`, and not `preventDefault()`, because I assume the removal code is actually another `click` handler set with delegation technique on ever-present parent element.